# CSS Responsive Slider Turn Vertical When Mobility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to start to create a responsive Slider on my web page.

But I want the slider to turn all the images to a vertical listing. It will be horizontal full width when full screen, then when it went to mobility all the images will be split to vertical to view.

I tried to search w3school for "media" method to change in the CSS files as shown below :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 370px) {
    .slick-slide img
    {
        float: left;
        display: block;

        overflow: hidden;
        list-style-type: square;
        position: relative; /* for the negative top distance to work */
        display: inline-block;
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

But no luck, there was no response at all. How can I make my slider the same as [Square Space](http://ishimoto-demo.squarespace.com/cujqsjul761xhugm0z07qodf9ozpot)? or are there any other methods I can try?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need `jQuery` to perform this action. For your convenience, slick allows you to turn your slider vertically using one single attribute. Your code should be something like this:

```
var wrapper = $("#wrapper-id-on-mobile");  

     wrapper.slick({   
      //some attributes    
        vertical: true
      });
```

Comment: In your jquery file, ya.

Comment: Yes, it turn to vertical already but it still within the wrapper, it does not split it to individual image listing. Any other attribute should i add?